# How to send notification on fixed build in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use email notifications in my Jenkins pipeline. What I want is to send a notification on failed build and a notification on fixed build. The first is really easy with a `try/catch` or `catchError` but I haven't found a solution for the latter.

Is it possible to send a notification for fixed builds in a Jenkins Pipeline ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Jenkins Class Mailer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mailer) to accomplish what you want by calling Mailer:

```
step([$class: 'Mailer',
      notifyEveryUnstableBuild: true,
      recipients: "example@example.com",
      sendToIndividuals: true])
```

in your `try/catch/finally` clause in `finally`. Mailer sends emails on fixed builds(by itself):

> 2. A successful build after a failed (or unstable) build triggers a new
>      e-mail, indicating that a crisis is over.

Another way is to manually check the status of the previous build and the current build and if they satisfy your requirements, then you send the email. You can do that following [this](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226419147-How-can-I-check-previous-build-status-in-a-Pipeline-Script-) resolution.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you :) I just had to set currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS' at the end of the try block in order to send email on fixed builds.

Comment: And instead of `try/catch/finally` you could use [jenkins pipeline post section](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/#cleaning-up-and-notifications).

Comment: @Andi Where would you put it ? I tried putting in always but then I lose fixed builds notifications.